# Working example of using socket.io to send packets of data between computers (not necessarily on the same network)?

Tags: javascript, html, networking, socket.io

I'm new to Socket.io, and I don't understand how to use Socket.io to set up a connection between two computers. I was able to complete the chat tutorial on the Socket.io website: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

This enables me to chat locally (on the same computer, multiple tabs) by connecting to localhost:5800. However, I cannot chat on multiple computers using this method, even if they are connected to the same network. I'm trying to use networking in an online game, so I looked at examples of networking in different games (such as this agar.io clone - https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone). All of the ones I've seen either assume the existence of other js files (files that are not relevant to my project) or they are too confusing for me to understand. Does anyone have a working example of a project that can send packets of data (e.g. a string such as "alive:true,speed:100") between computers?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The only difference between what you already have working and two separate computers on your network is that when computer A connects to your socket.io server on computer B, it needs to connect to either a DNS name or an IP address rather than `localhost`.  If this is just on your local network, it probably won't be a DNS name so you just need the local IP address of your socket.io server and you can connect to that.

Comment: If you want two client computers to communicate across different networks you will probably need to introduce a server computer that you control, to relay the messages. Client A sends a message to the server, destined for Client B, then the server forwards it to Client B if/when Client B is connected. This is because it is impossible for Client A and B to find each other on the internet without some kind of centralized registry, and even when Client A and B know each other's IP address, it is difficult to establish a direct connection between them via standard broadband routers.

Comment: @mfripp I'm not sure if the two computers finding each other is the main issue. I tried creating an ad hoc network using a third computer and allow the other two to connect to it, then tried accessing it with localhost:5800. The second computer (the one not hosting the code) could access the GUI, but any chats it sent would not be registered on either computer :(

Comment: You're going to have to show us your actual code and explain what debugging you've done before we can likely help you find the issue.  Questions about code here should always include the actual code.

Comment: @KevinJin, sorry, my comment missed the point a bit. The chat code you have is indeed designed to run on your main server, then other computers should connect to it to send/receive messages. My guess would be that you haven't setup the http server to listen on external network interfaces (i.e., on your local network). You may be able to get that to work by specifying `http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', <callback>)`. This tells the server to listen for connections from all network cards, not just internal connections (localhost or 127.0.0.1).

Comment: What does that last comment mean?  Where is the entirety of the code?

Comment: Sorry, that was sent accidentally.
@jfriend00 The entirety of my code that I've written so far can be found on https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example. That's the example I've been trying to use. The cord certainly works for multi-tabs but I have no idea how to change it so that it works with multiple computers. I haven't really done any debugging since I have little to no clue as to how the code works.

Comment: @mfripp Where should I put `http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.', <callback>)`?

Comment: @KevinJin, you would replace `http.listen(3000, function(){` on line 15 of chat.js with `http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0',  function(){`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code in chat.js:

```
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

to this:

```
http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The dummy address `'0.0.0.0'` tells the http server to listen for connections on all network addresses that your machine is currently using, i.e., on all network cards. Without this, the http server only listens on the machine's internal 'loopback' address (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`), which means it can only receive connections from other programs on the same machine.

If you want to use this to chat between two computers on different networks, you will need to run chat.js on a server that has a public IP address and doesn't have a firewall blocking the chat port (3000 in this case). Then you will need to point your chat clients at that address (eg 203.0.113.42:3000 or myhost.com:3000 if you've registered a hostname).

Comment: After making the change and running `node index.js` out of command prompt, I get "Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:5800" etc.

Comment: This worked fine for me, with exactly the change I described above (I was then able to connect from another computer in my local network). Are you sure you're not running the chat server twice at the same time? If I run it twice in two different terminal windows, I get the message you reported when I try to start the second one.